# R data.table group by range of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to group the R data.table according to a range of columns.
Without success so far. Is there any easy way how to do it?

Example:

```
library(data.table)

id <- c(1:1000) 
x1 <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T)
x2 <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T)
x3 <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T)
x4 <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T)
x5 <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T)

df<-data.frame(id,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
dt<-data.table(df)

dt[,.N,by=list(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)]
```

Now I would like to use something like

```
dt[,.N,by=list(x1:x5)]
```

but it, of course, does not work.
Do I miss a relatively simple approach to this problem?

Comment: `x1:x5` returns an error, what do you want `x1:x5` to actually be?

Comment: This is not available in versions prior v1.9.7 (the development version). You can download v1.9.7 from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) and it should work

Comment: read `?":"` in R before using it

Comment: @jan I don't think reading that helps. The syntax the OP is after is available, but not documented there. (Well, it's almost available, should be written as `by=x1:x5` not `by=list(x1:x5)`). As David mentioned the OP needs to upgrade (or wait for 1.9.8) and use the correct syntax.

Comment: x1:x5 was used just as an example.  Just looking for similar way of passing the range of variables to the data.table which would work.

Comment: @Frank I agree but `by=list()` evaluates content, so reading `:` is on point. But I am aware the issue here was not the `:` but lack of understanding that `list()` or `.()` in `by` evaluates expression provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `paste0()`:

```
dt[, .N, by = c(paste0("x", 1:5))]
```